# Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary

Tags: java, spring

In my Java spring application, I have

```
public class BinarySearchImpl {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("Quick")
    SortAlgorithem sorter;

    Log log=LogFactory.getLog(BinarySearchImpl.class);

    public BinarySearchImpl(SortAlgorithem sorter) {
        log.info("Binary Search Bean is created");
        this.sorter=sorter;
    }
```

`SortAlgorithem` is an interface which makes my application loosely coupled:

```
public interface SortAlgorithem {

    public int[] sort(int[] arrayNumbers);

}
```

And then there are 2 implementations for this interface. One is `BubbleSort`:

```
@Component
@Qualifier("Bubble")
public class BubbleSort implements SortAlgorithem {

    Log log=LogFactory.getLog(BubbleSort.class);

    public int[] sort(int[] numbers) {
        log.info("Bubble sort is called");
        return numbers;
    }
}
```

and the other is `QuickSort`:

```
@Component
@Qualifier("Quick")
//@Primary
public class QuickSort implements SortAlgorithem{

    Log log= LogFactory.getLog(QuickSort.class);

    public int[] sort(int[] numbers) {
        log.info("Quick Sort is called");
        return numbers;
    }

}
```

At the end, when I call my app it complains with this message:

```
Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

**I am wondering... Why `@Qualifier` annotation does not work?**

Comment: How does your `BinarySearchImpl` instance being created? Why do you need constructor param in it, since u r using field injection?

Comment: There will be some more text before the "Consider..." you quote. Include that in the question too.

Comment: Could you please add the import(s) statements?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have annotated a field with `@Autowired` and `@Qualifier`, but you have also created a constructor which sets the field.

I think that Spring is using the constructor, but doesn't automatically know that the constructor parameter corresponds to the annotated field.

So move the annotations into the constructor declaration:

```
private SortAlgorithm sorter;

@Autowired 
public BinarySearchImpl(@Qualifier("quick") SortAlgorithm sorter) {
     this.sorter = sorter;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a zero-arg constructor, keep your field annotation and let Spring inject using reflection. However in my opinion constructor-injection is better -- it allows you to unit test cleanly, without involving Spring or reflection.

As other answers point out, there are other ways to disambiguate autowired beans -- and the Spring docs explain them all -- but using qualifiers like this does work.

Answer (score 8):

### The correct approach:

```
public interface SortAlgorithem {
    public int[] sort(int[] arrayNumbers);
}

@Component("Bubble")
public class BubbleSort implements SortAlgorithem {
    Log log = LogFactory.getLog(BubbleSort.class);

    public int[] sort(int[] numbers) {
        log.info("Bubble sort is called");
        return numbers;
   }
}

@Primary
@Component("Quick")
public class QuickSort implements SortAlgorithem {
    Log log = LogFactory.getLog(QuickSort.class);

    public int[] sort(int[] numbers) {
        log.info("Quick Sort is called");
        return numbers;
    }
}
```

and then you need to use your implementations like this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = "Bubble")
private SortAlgorithem bubbleSort;

@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = "Quick")
private SortAlgorithem quickSort;
```

Comment: Yes, this is the right approach and works well for me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare your components like this:

```
@Component("Bubble")
public class BubbleSort implements SortAlgorithem {

    Log log=LogFactory.getLog(BubbleSort.class);

    public int[] sort(int[] numbers) {
        log.info("Bubble sort is called");
        return numbers;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Component("Quick")
public class QuickSort implements SortAlgorithem{

    Log log= LogFactory.getLog(QuickSort.class);

    public int[] sort(int[] numbers) {
        log.info("Quick Sort is called");
        return numbers;
    }

}
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: Yes, but the question is "why doesn't `@Qualifier` work"?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Sorry for coming late to the party.
I had 2 service class which were implementing a single interface like this,So
I have done this with `@Component("name")` and it worked.
though it is still a mystery why `@Qualifier("name")` did not worked?

Code:

```
@Service("signup")
//@Qualifier("signup")
public class SignUpGenerator implements ITestCaseGenerator {

}




@Component
public class SelUtil {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("login")
    ITestCaseGenerator login;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("signup")
    ITestCaseGenerator signUp;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@Component("qualifier_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when using @RequiredArgsConstructor annotation, and had to remove it (and use manual constructor with a @Qualifier annotation as per [@slim answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47262648/336558)).

Comment: In my IntelliJ 2021.2.3 there is a helpful message for this: `Lombok does not copy the annotation 'org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier' into the constructor`.