# How to use my TemplateEngine Bean not the Spring boot Bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-mail, thymeleaf

I am tring to add a Contact Form example with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf to my application.

I followed this example from GitHub : [thymeleafexamples-springmail](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleafexamples-springmail)

The **SpringMailConfig** class to configure a Mail Sender.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.EnvironmentAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;
import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ITemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.StringTemplateResolver;

//Configure a Mail Sender object

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:mail/emailconfig.properties")
public class SpringMailConfig implements ApplicationContextAware, EnvironmentAware {

    public static final String EMAIL_TEMPLATE_ENCODING = "UTF-8";

    private static final String JAVA_MAIL_FILE = "classpath:mail/javamail.properties";

    private static final String HOST = "mail.server.host";
    private static final String PORT = "mail.server.port";
    private static final String PROTOCOL = "mail.server.protocol";
    private static final String USERNAME = "mail.server.username";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "mail.server.password";


    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private Environment environment;



    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(final Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }


    /*
     * SPRING + JAVAMAIL: JavaMailSender instance, configured via .properties files.
     */
    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender mailSender() throws IOException {

        final JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

        // Basic mail sender configuration, based on emailconfig.properties
        mailSender.setHost(this.environment.getProperty(HOST));
        mailSender.setPort(Integer.parseInt(this.environment.getProperty(PORT)));
        mailSender.setProtocol(this.environment.getProperty(PROTOCOL));
        mailSender.setUsername(this.environment.getProperty(USERNAME));
        mailSender.setPassword(this.environment.getProperty(PASSWORD));

        // JavaMail-specific mail sender configuration, based on javamail.properties
        final Properties javaMailProperties = new Properties();
        javaMailProperties.load(this.applicationContext.getResource(JAVA_MAIL_FILE).getInputStream());
        mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProperties);

        return mailSender;

    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource emailMessageSource() {
        final ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("mail/MailMessages");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public TemplateEngine emailTemplateEngine() {
        final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        // Resolver for TEXT emails
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(textTemplateResolver());
        // Resolver for HTML emails (except the editable one)
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(htmlTemplateResolver());
        // Resolver for HTML editable emails (which will be treated as a String)
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(stringTemplateResolver());
        // Message source, internationalization specific to emails
        templateEngine.setTemplateEngineMessageSource(emailMessageSource());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver textTemplateResolver() {
        final ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setOrder(Integer.valueOf(1));
        templateResolver.setResolvablePatterns(Collections.singleton("text/*"));
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/mail/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".txt");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.TEXT);
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(EMAIL_TEMPLATE_ENCODING);
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        return templateResolver;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver() {
        final ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setOrder(Integer.valueOf(2));
        templateResolver.setResolvablePatterns(Collections.singleton("html/*"));
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/mail/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(EMAIL_TEMPLATE_ENCODING);
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        return templateResolver;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver stringTemplateResolver() {
        final StringTemplateResolver templateResolver = new StringTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setOrder(Integer.valueOf(3));
        // No resolvable pattern, will simply process as a String template everything not previously matched
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        return templateResolver;
    }
}
```

The **EmailService** class to send mails:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamSource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.context.Context;

import com.example.springmail.configuration.SpringMailConfig;

//Service to send mails

@Service
public class EmailService {

    private static final String EMAIL_TEXT_TEMPLATE_NAME = "text/email-text";
    private static final String EMAIL_SIMPLE_TEMPLATE_NAME = "html/email-simple";
    private static final String EMAIL_WITHATTACHMENT_TEMPLATE_NAME = "html/email-withattachment";
    private static final String EMAIL_INLINEIMAGE_TEMPLATE_NAME = "html/email-inlineimage";
    private static final String EMAIL_EDITABLE_TEMPLATE_CLASSPATH_RES = "classpath:mail/editablehtml/email-editable.html";

    private static final String BACKGROUND_IMAGE = "mail/editablehtml/images/background.png";
    private static final String LOGO_BACKGROUND_IMAGE = "mail/editablehtml/images/logo-background.png";
    private static final String THYMELEAF_BANNER_IMAGE = "mail/editablehtml/images/thymeleaf-banner.png";
    private static final String THYMELEAF_LOGO_IMAGE = "mail/editablehtml/images/thymeleaf-logo.png";

    private static final String PNG_MIME = "image/png";

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @Autowired
    private TemplateEngine htmlTemplateEngine;

    @Autowired
    private TemplateEngine textTemplateEngine;

    @Autowired
    private TemplateEngine stringTemplateEngine;



    /* 
     * Send plain TEXT mail 
     */
    public void sendTextMail(
        final String recipientName, final String recipientEmail, final Locale locale)
        throws MessagingException {

        // Prepare the evaluation context
        final Context ctx = new Context(locale);
        ctx.setVariable("name", recipientName);
        ctx.setVariable("subscriptionDate", new Date());
        ctx.setVariable("hobbies", Arrays.asList("Cinema", "Sports", "Music"));

        // Prepare message using a Spring helper
        final MimeMessage mimeMessage = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        final MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, "UTF-8");
        message.setSubject("Example plain TEXT email");
        message.setFrom("thymeleaf@example.com");
        message.setTo(recipientEmail);

        // Create the plain TEXT body using Thymeleaf
        final String textContent = this.textTemplateEngine.process(EMAIL_TEXT_TEMPLATE_NAME, ctx);
        message.setText(textContent);

        // Send email
        this.mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
    }


    /* 
     * Send HTML mail (simple) 
     */
    public void sendSimpleMail(
        final String recipientName, final String recipientEmail, final Locale locale)
        throws MessagingException {

        // Prepare the evaluation context
        final Context ctx = new Context(locale);
        ctx.setVariable("name", recipientName);
        ctx.setVariable("subscriptionDate", new Date());
        ctx.setVariable("hobbies", Arrays.asList("Cinema", "Sports", "Music"));

        // Prepare message using a Spring helper
        final MimeMessage mimeMessage = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        final MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, "UTF-8");
        message.setSubject("Example HTML email (simple)");
        message.setFrom("thymeleaf@example.com");
        message.setTo(recipientEmail);

        // Create the HTML body using Thymeleaf
        final String htmlContent = this.htmlTemplateEngine.process(EMAIL_SIMPLE_TEMPLATE_NAME, ctx);
        message.setText(htmlContent, true /* isHtml */);

        // Send email
        this.mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
    }


    /* 
     * Send HTML mail with attachment. 
     */
    public void sendMailWithAttachment(
        final String recipientName, final String recipientEmail, final String attachmentFileName,
        final byte[] attachmentBytes, final String attachmentContentType, final Locale locale)
        throws MessagingException {

        // Prepare the evaluation context
        final Context ctx = new Context(locale);
        ctx.setVariable("name", recipientName);
        ctx.setVariable("subscriptionDate", new Date());
        ctx.setVariable("hobbies", Arrays.asList("Cinema", "Sports", "Music"));

        // Prepare message using a Spring helper
        final MimeMessage mimeMessage = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        final MimeMessageHelper message
            = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true /* multipart */, "UTF-8");
        message.setSubject("Example HTML email with attachment");
        message.setFrom("thymeleaf@example.com");
        message.setTo(recipientEmail);

        // Create the HTML body using Thymeleaf
        final String htmlContent = this.htmlTemplateEngine.process(EMAIL_WITHATTACHMENT_TEMPLATE_NAME, ctx);
        message.setText(htmlContent, true /* isHtml */);

        // Add the attachment
        final InputStreamSource attachmentSource = new ByteArrayResource(attachmentBytes);
        message.addAttachment(
            attachmentFileName, attachmentSource, attachmentContentType);

        // Send mail
        this.mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
    }


    /* 
     * Send HTML mail with inline image
     */
    public void sendMailWithInline(
        final String recipientName, final String recipientEmail, final String imageResourceName,
        final byte[] imageBytes, final String imageContentType, final Locale locale)
        throws MessagingException {

        // Prepare the evaluation context
        final Context ctx = new Context(locale);
        ctx.setVariable("name", recipientName);
        ctx.setVariable("subscriptionDate", new Date());
        ctx.setVariable("hobbies", Arrays.asList("Cinema", "Sports", "Music"));
        ctx.setVariable("imageResourceName", imageResourceName); // so that we can reference it from HTML

        // Prepare message using a Spring helper
        final MimeMessage mimeMessage = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        final MimeMessageHelper message
            = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true /* multipart */, "UTF-8");
        message.setSubject("Example HTML email with inline image");
        message.setFrom("thymeleaf@example.com");
        message.setTo(recipientEmail);

        // Create the HTML body using Thymeleaf
        final String htmlContent = this.htmlTemplateEngine.process(EMAIL_INLINEIMAGE_TEMPLATE_NAME, ctx);
        message.setText(htmlContent, true /* isHtml */);

        // Add the inline image, referenced from the HTML code as "cid:${imageResourceName}"
        final InputStreamSource imageSource = new ByteArrayResource(imageBytes);
        message.addInline(imageResourceName, imageSource, imageContentType);

        // Send mail
        this.mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
    }


    /* 
     * Send HTML mail with inline image
     */
    public String getEditableMailTemplate() throws IOException {
        final Resource templateResource = this.applicationContext.getResource(EMAIL_EDITABLE_TEMPLATE_CLASSPATH_RES);
        final InputStream inputStream = templateResource.getInputStream();
        return IOUtils.toString(inputStream, SpringMailConfig.EMAIL_TEMPLATE_ENCODING);
    }


    /*
     * Send HTML mail with inline image
     */
    public void sendEditableMail(
            final String recipientName, final String recipientEmail, final String htmlContent,
            final Locale locale)
            throws MessagingException {

        // Prepare message using a Spring helper
        final MimeMessage mimeMessage = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        final MimeMessageHelper message
                = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true /* multipart */, "UTF-8");
        message.setSubject("Example editable HTML email");
        message.setFrom("thymeleaf@example.com");
        message.setTo(recipientEmail);

        // Prepare the evaluation context
        final Context ctx = new Context(locale);
        ctx.setVariable("name", recipientName);
        ctx.setVariable("subscriptionDate", new Date());
        ctx.setVariable("hobbies", Arrays.asList("Cinema", "Sports", "Music"));

        // Create the HTML body using Thymeleaf
        final String output = stringTemplateEngine.process(htmlContent, ctx);
        message.setText(output, true /* isHtml */);

        // Add the inline images, referenced from the HTML code as "cid:image-name"
        message.addInline("background", new ClassPathResource(BACKGROUND_IMAGE), PNG_MIME);
        message.addInline("logo-background", new ClassPathResource(LOGO_BACKGROUND_IMAGE), PNG_MIME);
        message.addInline("thymeleaf-banner", new ClassPathResource(THYMELEAF_BANNER_IMAGE), PNG_MIME);
        message.addInline("thymeleaf-logo", new ClassPathResource(THYMELEAF_LOGO_IMAGE), PNG_MIME);

        // Send mail
        this.mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
    }
}
```

The **SendingController** class that calls the service to send mails:

```
import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import com.example.springmail.service.EmailService;

//Controller method that calls the service to send mails

@Controller
public class SendingController {

    @Autowired
    private EmailService emailService;

    /* Send plain TEXT mail */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/sendMailText", method = POST)
    public String sendTextMail(
        @RequestParam("recipientName") final String recipientName,
        @RequestParam("recipientEmail") final String recipientEmail,
        final Locale locale)
        throws MessagingException {

        this.emailService.sendTextMail(recipientName, recipientEmail, locale);
        return "redirect:sent.html";

    }

    /* Send HTML mail (simple) */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/sendMailSimple", method = POST)
    public String sendSimpleMail(
        @RequestParam("recipientName") final String recipientName,
        @RequestParam("recipientEmail") final String recipientEmail,
        final Locale locale)
        throws MessagingException {

        this.emailService.sendSimpleMail(recipientName, recipientEmail, locale);
        return "redirect:sent.html";

    }

    /* Send HTML mail with attachment. */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/sendMailWithAttachment", method = POST)
    public String sendMailWithAttachment(
        @RequestParam("recipientName") final String recipientName,
        @RequestParam("recipientEmail") final String recipientEmail,
        @RequestParam("attachment") final MultipartFile attachment,
        final Locale locale)
        throws MessagingException, IOException {

        this.emailService.sendMailWithAttachment(
            recipientName, recipientEmail, attachment.getOriginalFilename(),
            attachment.getBytes(), attachment.getContentType(), locale);
        return "redirect:sent.html";

    }

    /* Send HTML mail with inline image */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/sendMailWithInlineImage", method = POST)
    public String sendMailWithInline(
        @RequestParam("recipientName") final String recipientName,
        @RequestParam("recipientEmail") final String recipientEmail,
        @RequestParam("image") final MultipartFile image,
        final Locale locale)
        throws MessagingException, IOException {

        this.emailService.sendMailWithInline(
            recipientName, recipientEmail, image.getName(),
            image.getBytes(), image.getContentType(), locale);
        return "redirect:sent.html";

    }

    /* Send editable HTML mail */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/sendEditableMail", method = POST)
    public String sendMailWithInline(
        @RequestParam("recipientName") final String recipientName,
        @RequestParam("recipientEmail") final String recipientEmail,
        @RequestParam("body") final String body,
        final Locale locale)
        throws MessagingException, IOException {

        this.emailService.sendEditableMail(
            recipientName, recipientEmail, body, locale);
        return "redirect:sent.html";

    }
}
```

but I could not launch the application.

> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> Description:
>
> Field htmlTemplateEngine in
>   com.example.springmail.service.EmailService required a single bean,
>   but 2 were found:
>     - emailTemplateEngine: defined by method 'emailTemplateEngine' in class path resource
>   [com/example/springmail/configuration/SpringMailConfig.class]
>     - templateEngine: defined by method 'templateEngine' in class path resource [com/example/springmail/web/SpringWebConfig.class]
>
> Action:
>
> Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer
>   to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean
>   that should be consumed

I have other class configurations may be cause this problem.

I found the same problem on another question but it did not work for me.
[Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47262363/consider-marking-one-of-the-beans-as-primary)

how to use **@Primary** and **@Qualifier** annotation in my case?

The **WebMvcConfig** class for Spring MVC and Thymeleaf configuration:

```
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {
        @Autowired
        private ErrorAttributes errorAttributes;

        @Bean
        public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
            return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
        }

        @Bean
        public AppErrorController appErrorController() {
            return new AppErrorController(errorAttributes);
        }

        @Bean
        public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
            final ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
            messageSource.setBasename("Messages");
            return messageSource;
        }

        private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

        @Override
        public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
            this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        }

        /*
         * Multipart resolver (needed for uploading attachments from web form)
         */
        @Bean
        public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
            final CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
            multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(10485760); // 10MBytes
            return multipartResolver;
        }

        /* **************************************************************** */
        /* THYMELEAF-SPECIFIC ARTIFACTS */
        /* TemplateResolver <- TemplateEngine <- ViewResolver */
        /* **************************************************************** */

        @Bean

    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        // SpringResourceTemplateResolver automatically integrates with Spring's
        // own
        // resource resolution infrastructure, which is highly recommended.
        final SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        // HTML is the default value, added here for the sake of clarity.
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        // Template cache is true by default. Set to false if you want
        // templates to be automatically updated when modified.
        templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
        return templateResolver;
    }
//problem
    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        // SpringTemplateEngine automatically applies SpringStandardDialect and
        // enables Spring's own MessageSource message resolution mechanisms.
        final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        // Enabling the SpringEL compiler with Spring 4.2.4 or newer can
        // speed up execution in most scenarios, but might be incompatible
        // with specific cases when expressions in one template are reused
        // across different data types, so this flag is "false" by default
        // for safer backwards compatibility.
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        final ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

The problem is with emailTemplateEngine() and templateEngine() Beans.

This is the architecture of spring elements may be It will better help to understand the problem.

[image: Spring elements]

templateEngine Bean:

```
@Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }
```

emailTemplateEngine Bean:

```
@Bean
public TemplateEngine emailTemplateEngine() {
    final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    // Resolver for TEXT emails
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(textTemplateResolver());
    // Resolver for HTML emails (except the editable one)
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(htmlTemplateResolver());
    // Resolver for HTML editable emails (which will be treated as a String)
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(stringTemplateResolver());
    // Message source, internationalization specific to emails
    templateEngine.setTemplateEngineMessageSource(emailMessageSource());
    return templateEngine;
}
```

Spring boot also has a bean for TemplateEngine defined in:

> org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafDefaultConfiguration.class

I couldn't use @Primary annotation or @Qualifier.

Comment: Hm, so there were 2 definitions of the `EmailService` class, and Spring doesn't know which one to use. In your case, the `@Qualifier` annotation lets you decide on a specific definition to use. (ie, `@Qualifier('SpringWebConfig')` or whatever it's called in there. This lets Spring differentiate between which bean to use. Similarly, `@Primary` does something similar by breaking the priority tie by letting you annotate one of the `EmailServices` as the "main bean to use". Not sure if this applies to your case, so I left this as a comment...

Comment: @Raizuri hi, where I have to put exactly the `@Qualifier` annotation ?

Comment: You put the `@Qualifier` notation on the duplicate bean. In your case, in your controller, you have `@Autowired / private EmailService`. You should have something like `@Qualifer('YourOtherBeanDefinition`) / @Autowired / private EmailService`

Comment: where is your SpringWebConfig class. Can you put that code as well

Comment: @pvpkiran I have other class configurations may be cause this problem. I added the SpringWebConfig class.

Comment: @Raizuri your solution did not work: `Field emailService in com.example.springmail.controller.SendingController required a bean of type 'com.example.springmail.service.EmailService' that could not be found. Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.springmail.service.EmailService' in your configuration.`

Comment: Do you have any xml files with Bean definitions?

Comment: @Raizuri no i don't have xml file for Bean definitions.

Comment: @Raizuri I have problem with emailTemplateEngine() and templateEngine() Beans.

Comment: How many `@Bean` annotations do you have on the same class? (eg, you might have `@Bean public EmailTemplate getX()` and `@Bean public EmailTemplate getY()`)

Comment: @Raizuri I checked all my class it does not have beans that return the same thing. also I could not launch the  gitHub example "thymeleafexamples-springmail". I add the same class of github in my project and it does not work always the same error.

Comment: why I am getting this error?

Comment: @Raizuri I added the architecture of spring elements to better understand the problem pls check It.

Comment: @Raizuri, Spring boot also has a bean for TemplateEngine. this is the problem.